# building divs in loop and show them on button press angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-ng-if

I want to make divs in loop and show the div I choose by press of specific button.
In theory I see this like the following...
using *ngFor i construct divs and buttons for them
lets say

```
<div>div1</div><button (click)="showDiv(divID)">showDIV</button>
```

To hide div I must use ngIf

```
 <div *ngIf="Here I must place something wih divID">>div1</div><button (click)="showDiv(divID)">showDIV</button>
```

And in ts file I must set value of something with divID to TRUE when I press it's button.

So how can I do that something, I guess it must be array or something else.
Please give me solution example of what must be written in template and ts file

part of ts file for dynamical array building.

```
data.length=6
i=1
        data.forEach(element => {
Here I want to add variable to array
          this.i++;
        });
```

Comment: It looks like you just need a kind of switch button, with states "on" and "off". It's not clear if you need to control that state at the parent component, so I'd rather say that a notify event would be just fine? 

Look at this example from a fellow Brazilian: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-compound-content-child?file=app%2Ftoggle%2Ftoggle.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an array in the controller like

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  buttons = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      this.buttons.push({
        id: i, show: false
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And use it to display the buttons dynamically in the template

```html
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button (mouseup)="button.show = !button.show">
    {{ button?.show ? ('Hide ' + button?.id) : ('Show ' + button?.id) }}
  </button>
  <ng-container *ngIf="button?.show">
    Content for button {{ button?.id }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ivuvqf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Docs: [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) and [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directives, [expression interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#interpolation-), [`<ng-container>` tag](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container).

If you're new to Angular, I'd also recommend you to go through the official [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces all these basics.

Comment: That's what I want to do! Just the additional thing though is that I must constuct that array dinamically in on init part of ts file. Can you edit your answer ?

Comment: This is an example. You don't have to use it exactly as shown in it. You could assign the values in the `ngOnInit` hook as per you requirement.

Comment: Yes I understand that and will modify his code for my needs of course, Just because I'm aa bit new to angular want some example of how to build array on the go in a loop inside ngOnInit.

Comment: Thanks, but in a loop. I mean dinamically.

Comment: Please provide a pseudo example. You don't even show what sort of buttons you need.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please go through some examples like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) for simple Javascript loops. There are many good articles to be found.

Comment: There is no context of how your code looks. You need to provide your code.

Comment: fixed already and deleted my comment also for not bothering you. Sorry you already helped a lot. Once more thank you and sorry for bothering! :)

Comment: @David: You don't have to apologize. People know what they signed up for here. They just expect some sort of initiation and attempts from posts. :)

Comment: You're doing great job for all of us questioners here Michael, this is not the first and hope not the last question you've helped me perfectly and completely :) Thank you sir . Let all your problems be solved the same fast and easy way you solved my questions :)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your requirement as below.

***Please refer to the below example***
[image]
**Example code:**

***app.component.ts***

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  divisions = [
    {
      content: 'Div 1 content .......',
      visibility: false
    },
    {
      content: 'Div 2 content .......',
      visibility: false
    },
    {
      content: 'Div 3 content .......',
      visibility: false
    },
    {
      content: 'Div 4 content .......',
      visibility: false
    },
  ];

  toggleDiv(index: number) {
    this.divisions[index].visibility = !this.divisions[index].visibility;
  }
}
```

***app.component.html***

```html
<div class="container">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let div of divisions;let i=index">
    <div class="div-btn">
      <button type="button" (click)="toggleDiv(i)" class="btn btn-primary">{{div.visibility===false? 'Show': 'Hide' }}
       Div {{i+1}}</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="div.visibility" class="div-content">{{div.content}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

***app.component.css***

```css
.div-content {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div-btn{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I've already solved my problem with help of Michael, but thank you very much for your effort, You've created very nice answer with all those animations and details. Again thank you sir!